# I have a problem with the Duplicator plugin in the last stage that I am trying to login to the website

Tags: wordpress

When I want to transfer my site to the host with the help of the Duplicator plugin, in the last stage, which is logged in, I encounter a strange error. Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_check_php_mysql_versions () in /home3/babilyon/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 37
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to make an answer. What version of php are using? What version of WordPress?

Comment: Thanks for the replay, the problem was solved ... The main problem was the memory and it had to be increased.